# Running CMake on Amazon Linux

Tags: cmake, amazon-linux

I am trying to build OpenJpeg on an AWS Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I installed cmake and gcc and had no issues during installation. When I try to cmake openjpeg I get the following error:

```
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:44 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:164 (TEST_BIG_ENDIAN)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Checking the error logs it seems CMake is unable to determine the size of integers, shorts and longs. The full error log can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/redserpent7/596dc1f74fde92fe7a595f219bf68e8c#file-cmakeerror-log)

How can I work this out and make CMake work?

Answer (score 23):

Amazon has a guide: [Preparing to Compile Software](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html), which proposes the following command to install a C compiler.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Next, you can download and build Cmake yourself: [Install Cmake 3](https://www.matbra.com/2017/12/07/install-cmake-on-aws-linux.html0).

```
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.18/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.18.0
./bootstrap
make
sudo make install
```

Note: the last make actually needs sudo.

Comment: ./bootstrap   failed for me after a few minutes.
Could not find OpenSSL.  Install an OpenSSL development package or
  configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.

this helped me resolve: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-compile-dcmake-use-openssl-off/1271

Comment: @JordanKohn I've solved it via the second answer including `yum install sudo wget openssl-devel -y` first, though I needed to use `sudo` for it.

Answer (score 14):

This works in the most recent Amazon Linux image (Nov 2021):

```
# Install sudo, wget and openssl, which is required for building CMake
yum install sudo wget openssl-devel -y

# Install development tools
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y

# Download, build and install cmake
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.18/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.18.0
./bootstrap
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this does not actually answer why the error was happening but I was able to build OpenJpeg by building CMake from source. So I just removed Cmake which was installed via yum and I believe was 2.8.12. Downloaded the latest CMake3 sources (v 3.10) built Cmake and openjpeg and all my other packages with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [set up a Docker container](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) to replicate correct environment. This way, you could form a container on your local machine, make sure it all builds on the container environment, and later use this environment on the EC2.

There is a project on Github that provides a Docker image which can be used to compile for Lambda and test stuff locally. Have a look: https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

Comment: Thabks but I need to build directly on the instance as I will move the package binaries to AWS lambda

Comment: @ZaidAmir that's not a problem – have a look at this: https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

Comment: I honestly do not see how a container can solve this particular problem. The EC2 instance should replicate the lambda environment on its own. No need to add another layer of complexity to this.

Answer (score 0):

For `Amazon Linux 2023` you can install `cMake` with `dnf`: `dnf install cmake`.

Here's an example of building a `Docker` image with `Amazon Linux 2023` and `cMake`, for use as an `AWS Lambda Function`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Install cMake
RUN dnf install -y cmake

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

# Copy function code
COPY main.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "main.lambda_handler" ]
```